# flash : start at exactly frame on timeline

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I have a flash project with many frames. I want to test a small part of clip, but everytime I run, it runs from begin, so I must wait until come to exactly frame I want.

So,my question is : in flash cs6, how can I run from exactly frame on timeline.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is just animation on the timeline, you could insert a bit a of code:

```
gotoAndPlay(10); // would jump to frame 10 when flash hits this bit of code
```

on the first frame. You would put it in the script area for that frame. If however your project contains other code on the timeline that must be run (such as initializing or setup code), then you may have to emulate all of those before you can jump to a frame as it may skip it.